# Detect & remove 'www' in NSURL

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsurl, host

I have a macOS application. I need to remove the scheme and `www` part from any `NSURL`. This is what I have come up with:

```
// For testing purposes.
NSString *blogID = @"https://www.testing1234.tumblr.com";
    
// Create the corrected link string.
NSString *correctLink;
    
// Convert the string to a url.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:blogID];
    
// Check if the url has a scheme.
    
if ([url scheme] != nil) {
    correctLink = [url host];
} else {
    correctLink = blogID;
}
    
// Ensure there are enough characters before
// performing the necessary 'www.' checks.
    
if ([correctLink length] > 4) {
        
    // Remove the first instance of 'www.'
    // from the blog url link string.
        
    if ([[correctLink substringToIndex:4] containsString:@"www."]) {
        correctLink = [correctLink substringFromIndex:4];
    }
}
    
NSLog(@"correctLink: %@", correctLink);
```

My question is: how can I reliably remove the `www` part of the string? For starters aren't there different variants of `www` such as `www2`? Does `NSURL` have any method that allows me to detect the `www` part of the string? (Just like how I can detect the `http://` part of the string by calling `scheme`).

**Update**

I can't use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` because it will replace **all** occurrences of `www`. So if the URLhappens to be `www.testsitewww.tumblr.com` then it will become `testsite.tumblr.com`. That's not what I want, I only want to remove the first occurrence of `www` (or any other variants such as `www2`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way. You can separate the url by "." and you can get remaining string.

**- if www. or www2. or anything else comes it will separate by "." and you can get remaining string**

```
NSString *blogID = @"https://www.testing1234.tumblr.com";
    NSString *correctLink;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:blogID];
    if ([url scheme] != nil) {
        correctLink = [url host];
    } else {
        correctLink = blogID;
    }
    NSArray *arr = [correctLink componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    NSString *str = @"";
    for(int i=1; i<arr.count; i++)
    {
        str = [str stringByAppendingString:[arr objectAtIndex:i]];
        if(i != arr.count-1)
            str = [str stringByAppendingString:@"."];
    }
    NSLog(@"correctLink: %@", str); //correctLink: testing1234.tumblr.com
```

Comment: @Supertecnoboff updated the code and tested. please check it.

Comment: Works perfectly, just what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can replace part of text ex:

```
NSString* url = [urlWithWWW stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"www." withString:@""];
```

Comment: The problem with that, is that it will replace all occurrences of ```www```. So if the url happens to be ```www.testsitewww.tumblr.com``` then it will become ```testsite.tumblr.com```. That's not what I want, I only want to remove the first occurrence of ```www``` (or any other variants such as ```www2```).

Comment: You can check begin of text -> [string hasPrefix:@"www."] -> then substring

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
NSString *blogID = @"https://www.testing1234.tumblr.com";
[blogID stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"www" withString:@""];
//or
[blogID stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"www." withString:@""];
```

or

```
 if([blogID hasPrefix:@"www"]) {
//do stuff
 }
```

Comment: The problem with that, is that it will replace all occurrences of ```www```. So if the url happens to be ```www.testsitewww.tumblr.com``` then it will become ```testsite.tumblr.com```. That's not what I want, I only want to remove the first occurrence of ```www``` (or any other variants such as ```www2```).

Comment: @Supertecnoboff or you can split the string using on the basis of ".", and the pass the value into an array. Now you can loop through array and compare the string at every index with "WWW/WW2" according to your need and if the value at particular index matches "WWW/WW2" then you can leave that index data and can concatenate the rest of the index data and append the value in a string. In this way your problem will be solved.

Comment: Let me ask again if you are not getting my answer

Comment: see the change above